# No puedo importar la libreria compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8' para el codigo de Barra

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

quiero importar la libreria `compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9.8'` a mi app para utilizar el escanner de código de barras, pero me sale el siguiente error que no deja sincronisar el proyecto, le agredecería a todos algo de ayuda !!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes conexión a internet?

Comment: si tengo, lo que  no puedo actualizar los repositorios por mi ubicación  !!

Comment: Ups!!! te encuentras en Cuba?

Comment: asi es, amigo !!

Comment: Me pasaba lo mismo, pero al configurar la conexion proxy no me estaba tomando https revisa por si usas un proxy para tu conexion